# Trying to modify toString() method to get desired results

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have overridden the `toString` methods in my `Employee` class as shown below. This is returning `name` and `EmployeeId` simultaneously as one single string which I don't want because of the reasons explained below.

```
 @Entity
    public class Employee 
    {       
        public int getEmployeeId() {
            return EmployeeId;
        }

        public void setEmployeeId(int EmployeeId) {
            this.EmployeeId = EmployeeId;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Name:"+this.name+ "ID"+this.EmployeeId;
        }


        @Id
        @Column(name="Employee_ID")
        private int EmployeeId; 

        @Column(name="NAME")
        private String name;

    }
```

Since I am returning `name` and `EmployeeId` in the toString method, because of the following line :

```
responseJSON = GenericOrmStatusView.OrmStatusToJsonString(true, 1,empStatus, true);
```

I am getting the following JSON response :

```
{
  "status" : "SUCCESS",
  "empID" : 1,
  "empStatus" : [ "Name:JackID12", "Name:JohnID40", "Name:AndrewID27", "Name:TimothyID50", "Name:NikkiID65" ]
}
```

However, I would like to get the following response with all the empIDs printing next to empID and all the empStatus printing next to empStatus as shown below :

```
{
  "status" : "SUCCESS",
  "empID" : ["12","40","27","50","65"],
  "empStatus" : [ "Jack", "John", "Andrew", "Timothy", "Nikki" ]
}
```

How should I modify my `toString()` method in the `Employee` class so that I could achieve above JSON response?

Here is the code for my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get_employee_details", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateemployee
    (
            @RequestParam(value="emp_id", defaultValue="0") Integer emp_id,
            @RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="") String name
    ) 
    {
        String responseJSON = null;
        boolean getStatus = true;       
        try {
            EmployeeDao employeeDao = (EmployeeDao)context.getBean("employeeDao");
            Employee employee = null;           
            List<Employee> empList = employeeDao.findByEmployeeId(emp_id);
            if ((empList != null) && (!empList.isEmpty())) {

                List<String> empStatus = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(Employee emp : empList){
                empStatus.add(emp.toString());
                responseJSON = GenericOrmStatusView.OrmStatusToJsonString(true, 1,empStatus, true);
            }

            }                       
        }

        return responseJSON;
    }
```

Comment: By doing that, wouldn't you be violating the encapsulation of the data. How do you know the id 12 belongs to Jack in the Jason? (except that they occur at the same index position.)

Comment: I could not understand why overriding method when you can create a normal method and returns same response as you want.

Comment: @K139 You mean that by using the array list, the IDs can get printed in any order?

Comment: @Coder, Nope. Your json should be self-explanatory to the user without any confusion. Instead of grouping the data as you want, it is better to combine them under singe entity. like employee [{ id=12, name=jhon},....].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not understand why overriding method when you can create a normal method and returns the same response as you want.

Alternative just use as following:

```
public String addJoinString() {
  return String.format("Name: %d, ID: %d",this.name,this.EmployeeId); 
}
```

And in your `updateemployee` method use `emp.addJoinString()` instead of `emp.toString()`. The above code was just the sample to remove the error. Now when parsing use split with `comma` and use both values as you want.

For creating the response as desired by you can use other libraries like Google Gson, Jackson, or JSON

For example you use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

```
if ((empList != null) && (!empList.isEmpty())) {

   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
   obj.put("status","success");
   obj.put("name",new JSONArray());
   obj.put("id",new JSONArray());
   for(Employee emp : empList){
     obj.get("name") .put(emp.name);
     obj.get("id") .put(emp.id);
     responseJSON = obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is kind of doing the same thing as the overridden `toString()` method. Maybe I should find a way to return a JSON response from the method instead of trying to separate the ID and name in the controller and then printing it in the JSON format.

Comment: I was actually typing and by mistakenly pressed the post answer button. Have updated the stuff.

Comment: With the same response which you were getting, you can do the thing as splitting the string with the comma.